# How to add Script to instantiated object at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, addition, instantiation

I have a Script in my main Assets folder called `BezierWalk.cs`

In another script, `Spawn`, I'm trying to instantiate objects from Prefab `Sphere` and attach `BezierWalk.cs` to them.

`Spawn` script:

```
public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{

  public GameObject Sphere;
  //string ScriptName = "BezierWalk";

  void Start()
  {  
      Vector3 vSpawnPos = transform.position;

      for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
          var objectYouCreate = Instantiate(Sphere, vSpawnPos, transform.rotation);
          //objectYouCreate.AddComponent<T>("Assets/BezierWalk.cs");
          //objectYouCreate.AddComponent(typeof(ScriptName)) as ScriptName;
          //objectYouCreate.AddComponent<ScriptName>();
          //var myScript = Sphere.AddComponent<BezierWalk.cs>();
          vSpawnPos.z += 20;
        }       
   }
```

You can see commented out attempts...

How I am supposed to do this properly? Thank you.

Comment: Was some time since I worked with unity but shouldn't it be `objectYouCreate.AddComponent<ScriptName>();` and inside the parenthesises you put constructor arguments? I think there also was a way to add it with Instantiate but then you could just add in to the GameObject/prefab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at how you reference components in unity, the answer should be clear - did you try any of the ones you listed?

Reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html

The normally used is as it is easy reading

`objectYouCreate.AddComponent<ClassName>();`

You can use

`objectYouCreate.AddComponent(typeof(ClassName));`

the .cs is for humans, its your readable version. so you would never need the .cs reference in your code.

note: I mentioned it as ClassName rather than scriptname, as while they are the same in monobehaviors in unity, it isnt the same anywhere else in c# so, the important bit is not the name of the file you made, but the name of the class within it.

Another way is to have prefabs, make a prefab of your object with all the components you need already on it.

Comment: Thank you. That solves it… the problem is I was using a namespace in the BezierWalk script so I had to do `objectYouCreate.AddComponent<BezierNamespace.BezierWalk>();` . Oops.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the tips. I didn't know you could have the script already added to the Prefab. Am Newbie!

Answer (score 0):

If your script lies within certain namespace, you should follow the following format

`GameObject.AddComponent(typeof(namespace.className))`;